# Diagonalizing 4x4 block Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a $4\times4$ block matrix of the form $$M = \begin{pmatrix} H & A \\ A^\dagger & -H\end{pmatrix}$$ where $H=H^\dagger$ is a $2\times2$ self-adjoint matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, and $A$ is some general complex $2 \times 2$ matrix. I would like to compute the eigenvalues, is there a simpler way than computing $\text{det}(\xi \mathbb{I}-M)$ directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula, after which the computation boils down to simply evaluating $2\times2$ determinants.
Given a matrix $M$ in block form

$$
M= \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\C & D \end{pmatrix}
$$

we have

$$\det(M)=\det(A-BD^{-1}C)\det(D),$$

(valid when $D$ is invertible).

In your case

\begin{align}
A & =  H-\lambda \mathbb{I} \\
B & = A \\
C &= A^\dagger \\
D &= -H -\lambda \mathbb{I}.
\end{align}

The formula for the inverse of a $2\times2$ matrix is also quite simple.